# QUERY contendo diferente e ou

Tags: mysql

Estou precisando fazer uma query onde o status daquela pessoa pode ser A = Ativo, I = Inativo e B = Bloqueado porém pode ser também null, a minha query ja está retornando quando é A, B ou I porém quando está null não retorna nada.

```
select COD_IDENT_PESSO,
       TXT_NOMEX_PESSO,
       TXT_APELI_PESSO,
       case FLG_SEXOX_PESSO when 'F' then 'Feminino' when 'M' then 'Masculino' end as FLG_SEXOX_PESSO,
       if(DAT_NASCI_PESSO is null, '', date_format(DAT_NASCI_PESSO, '%d/%m/%Y')) as DAT_NASCI_PESSO,
       case FLG_STATU_PESSO when 'A' then 'Ativo' when 'I' then 'Inativo' when 'B' then 'Bloqueado' end as FLG_STATU_PESSO,
       if(DAT_ADMIS_PESSO is null, '', date_format(DAT_ADMIS_PESSO, '%d/%m/%Y')) as DAT_ADMIS_PESSO
       from DB_EGLISE.tbl_PESSOAS
       where COD_IDENT_IGREJ = 'ibar'
       and FLG_STATU_PESSO <> 'A' or //PROBLEMA ESTA AQUI
       FLG_STATU_PESSO = null //E AQUI
       order by TXT_NOMEX_PESSO
```

Na minha query preciso que retorne tudo que seja diferente de A ou que seja nulo.

Comment: Tenta com  `AND (FLG_STATU_PESSO IS NULL OR FLG_STATU_PESSO <> 'A')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem que usar o *IS NULL* quando quiser que a buscar retorne somente valores **NULL** ou *IS NOT NULL* quando quiser que somente retorne valores diferentes de **NULL**.

altera as linhas.

> and FLG_STATU_PESSO <> 'A' or //PROBLEMA ESTA AQUI
>
> FLG_STATU_PESSO = null //E AQUI

Para

> and (FLG_STATU_PESSO <> 'A' or FLG_STATU_PESSO is null)

```
select COD_IDENT_PESSO,
       TXT_NOMEX_PESSO,
       TXT_APELI_PESSO,
       case FLG_SEXOX_PESSO when 'F' then 'Feminino' when 'M' then 'Masculino' end as FLG_SEXOX_PESSO,

       if(DAT_NASCI_PESSO is null, '', date_format(DAT_NASCI_PESSO, '%d/%m/%Y')) as DAT_NASCI_PESSO,

       case FLG_STATU_PESSO when 'A' then 'Ativo' when 'I' then 'Inativo' when 'B' then 'Bloqueado' end as FLG_STATU_PESSO,
       if(DAT_ADMIS_PESSO is null, '', date_format(DAT_ADMIS_PESSO, '%d/%m/%Y')) as DAT_ADMIS_PESSO
       from DB_EGLISE.tbl_PESSOAS

       where COD_IDENT_IGREJ = 'ibar'
       and (FLG_STATU_PESSO <> 'A' or FLG_STATU_PESSO is null)
       order by TXT_NOMEX_PESSO
```

Comment: Vlw deu certinho.